# Set Http Basic Authentication at the project level (web.config)

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config, basic-authentication

Any way to do this?  I've seen every other config file referenced but this one (Usually IIS) but I need it to be portable with the project.  I have this one project that I need to demo with basic HTTP authentication over SSL, and I would not have thought this would be the hard part.

Comment: do a google search on the following `C# stackoverflow basic HTTP authentication over SSL` also here is a working example here [Sending Basic Authentication over http](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989761/sending-basic-authentication-over-http)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put this code in the web.config file under system.web element:

```
 <security>
  <authentication>
   <anonymousAuthentication enabled="false" />
   <basicAuthentication enabled="true" />
  </authentication>
 </security>
```

Bear in mind that Basic Auth. must have been enabled on the server (through Turn On/Off Windows features)

Comment: As a note, in VS2015 this configuration file is in the solution folder.