# Having trouble adding authentication to WCF service client using C#

Tags: c#, wcf

I am calling a WCF service using the follwing code:

```
string certPath = @"C:\certs\mycert.pem";
var uri = new Uri("http://Myserver/TestService.svc/MyMethod/parm1/parm2");
X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(certPath);
var request = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("user", "password");
request.PreAuthenticate = true;
request.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
var response = request.GetResponse();
```

But getting

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

error and

> No Proxy-Authenticate Header is present

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try

```html
string urlAddress = "http://www.google.com";
string userName = "user01";
string password = "puser01";
string proxyServer = "127.0.0.1";
int proxyPort = 8081;

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(urlAddress);

if (userName != string.Empty)
{
    request.Proxy = new WebProxy(proxyServer, proxyPort)
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(userName, password)
    };

    string basicAuthBase64 = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetBytes(string.Format("{0}:{1}", userName, password)));
    request.Headers.Add("Proxy-Authorization", string.Format("Basic {0}", basicAuthBase64));
}
```

Reference:[Sending Basic authentication over http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28989761/sending-basic-authentication-over-http)

Comment: Where do I get the proxy server and port from? Are they random?